# error with freebsd uwsgi

Tags: freebsd, uwsgi

I have a error with uwsgi

when i start my config - uwsgi bottle.ini

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
setgid() to 80
setuid() to 80
your processes number limit is 5547
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 58982
lock engine: ipcsem
uwsgi_lock_ipcsem_init()/semget(): No space left on device [core/lock.c line 507]
uwsgi_ipcsem_clear()/semctl(): Invalid argument [core/lock.c line 631]
```

my bottle.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 185.21.214.275:80
chdir = /usr/local/www/myapp/
virtualenv = /usr/local/www/mypython
master = true
wsgi-file = /usr/local/www/myapp/app.py
uid = www
gid = www
```

I have had reinstalled uwsgi and pcre but proble is still appeare

Answer (score 1):

It is explained here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

`On OpenBSD, NetBSD and FreeBSD < 9, SysV IPC semaphores are used as the locking subsystem. These operating systems tend to limit the number of allocable semaphores to fairly small values. You should raise the default limits if you plan to run more than one uWSGI instance. FreeBSD 9 has POSIX semaphores, so you do not need to bother with that.`